# Remove next line visibility in multiline Edittext android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a Multiline Edittext of fixed height, 30dp. I need to show only a single line at once. But when user enters multiple lines and scrolls up, user can see some part of the next line (as shown in image 2). It should not happen. I need only one line with the top and bottom spacing like in image 1 without removing the multiline feature.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"/>
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Tried removing: `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`?

Comment: @Shaishav That totally removed the multiline feature

Comment: I thought maybe if we increase the line spacing, they would appear independently enough. So, I found `android:lineSpacingMultiplier` and `android:lineSpacingExtra`, but neither appear to work for me :( (apparently their implementation is buggy in lollipop+ devices)

Comment: Maybe its about padding.. getPaddingTop, getExtendedPaddingTop, getCompoundPaddingTop all returned 0, whereas getTotalPaddingTop returns a positve integer..

Answer (score 1):

This [almost] appears okay to me:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"/>
```

Comment: That brought down the text a little bit down, but the next line is still visible :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow user to see only last line of text, you can do following:

- use single line input
- if user enters "\n", store current text somewhere, and clear text in input

You should be able to do it e.g. with [InputFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) or
[onKeyDown()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown(int,%20android.view.KeyEvent))

Comment: No, all text needs to be present so that user can be able to drag up and down using the cursor handle.